# Open Graph Layout

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

How can I create a Facebook Open Graph Story with this layout?

[image]

In developers I don`t see this layout attachament ...

Comment: Is this not just how Facebook groups multiple stories?

Comment: When you found the answer, _post an answer_. Answers do not go in questions.

Comment: Thank you, i post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default layout is the one from the picture but be careful if you have a picture smaller than 200/200px will get another layout (simple link layout).